# Facebook new share sdks containing non public API usage

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios8

With the new Facebook share sdks v4.0.1 - i am getting the no-public selector warning for previewImageURL,suggestions,to.

I changed the name and added fb_... and archiving again but it also showing same.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, Downloaded full sdks code from here - https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

And done changes of variables and build the sdks and using that sdk will solved the issue.